# How to set android:layout_alignParentLeft attribute to imageview in code?

Tags: android, layout

I want to achieve the same thing in code as it is in this xml (this imageview is inside relative layout):

```
                          <ImageView   
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:src="@drawable/logo"/>
```

I know how to set layout width and height, but don't know how to set layout_alignParentLeft="true".

Is it possbile to do this in code?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = 
    new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
imageView.setLayoutParams(params);
```

Answer (score 0):

When adding an element to a layout in code, you can provide `LayoutParams`.  In this case, you want to use [RelativeLayout.LayoutParms](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.html).

You can add a [rule](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.html#addRule%28int%29) to the params to tell it that youwant to ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT.