# Android align top bitmap in imageview

Tags: android, android-imageview

Is there anyway so I can align bitmap in `ImageView`. I have an issue with my image view. I'm setting it's source via Java Code and after bitmap is resized it's centered in `ImageView`, but the thing that I want is to align the bitmap.

Declaring the imageView :

```
    <RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/collection_background"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/actionbar" > 


     <ImageView  
        android:id="@+id/collection_image_background"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:contentDescription="@string/stampii"  />

    // countinue ........
```

and here is how I'm setting the bitmap :

```
BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    o2.inTempStorage = new byte[8*1024];

    ops = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(cis,null,o2);
    ImageView view = (ImageView) findViewById (R.id.collection_image_background);        
    view.setImageBitmap(ops);
```

Any ides how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you can scale your bitmap depending on your screen size and set it as source of your `ImageView`. You can use something like this :

```
int screenWidth = getWindow().getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getWidth();
    Log.e("","screen width : "+screenWidth);
    //int screenHeight = getWindow().getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getHeight();

    int width = ops.getWidth();
    Log.e("","bitmap width : "+width);
    int height = ops.getHeight();
    Log.e("","bitmap height : "+height);

    float scale = 0;
    if(width>height){
        scale = (float) width / (float) height;
    } else if(height>width){
        scale = (float) height / (float) width;
    }
    Log.e("","scale : "+scale);

    float newWidth = (float) screenWidth * scale;

    Log.d("","new height : "+newWidth);

    Bitmap scaledBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(ops, screenWidth, (int) newWidth, true);
    Log.e("","new bitmap width : "+scaledBitmap.getWidth());
    Log.e("","new bitmap height : "+scaledBitmap.getHeight());

    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(screenWidth, (int)newWidth);
    params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
    view.setLayoutParams(params);
    view.setImageBitmap(scaledBitmap);
```

Try this and just hit me up if it's working or not.

Answer (score 26):

Add `android:scaleType="fitStart"` to your **ImageView**. It is ok for me.

Comment: This one aligns to the top left of the ImageView, not top center.

Answer (score 2):

Additionally to the answers above you can set it programmatically with `scaleType`:

```
image.scaleType = ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_START
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`setLayoutParams`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setLayoutParams(android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams)), as shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4819982/67063).

**EDIT**

Your problem is that you've specified the view to be as wide as its parent, while the loaded bitmap may be considerably thinner.

Try to make the view only as wide as needed by using this attribute instead:

```
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
```

Comment: actually i can saw that the imageview is aligned at the top of it's parent, but the bitmap in imageview is centered..which I am trying to fix

Comment: Looks like your problem is aligning the bitmap *within the view*, not the view within its parent. Let me check on this...

Comment: yeah, that's my problem.sorry if i asked the question a little harder to understand.

Comment: If i set `android:layout_width="wrap_content"` it's actually setting the width of my imageview as width of the bitmap..which is like 320px, but I need to set it to `fill_parent`, because in big screen size the image will be too small.

Answer (score 1):

You can use android:scaleType to change the alignement in your ImageView.

Comment: which option I can use to center bitmap in imageview and align it at the top of view, because I didn't find anything like this.

Comment: if I understand good, it's android:scaleType="fitCenter" and android:gravity="top"

Comment: @FUBUs ImageView doesn't have property gravity.